# How to find mysql-connecor-cpp package in a CMake project?

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector

I'm trying to build a project with `mysql-connecor-cpp` using CMake `find_package` command. I need to use `jdbc` because I need to use legacy codes. I'm working on RHEL8 and `Package mysql-connector-c++-devel-8.1.0-1.el8.x86_64 is already installed.` The module script I'm using is [FindMysqlConnectorCpp.cmake](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/attachments/20100607/c11f3ae3/attachment-0001.obj). But I think it needs an update for `mysql-connector-c++-8.1.0` since they moved legacy codes under `JDBC`. I want to be able to use `JDBC`. What update should I make on find module?

Here is my file tree:

```
cmake/
├─ Modules/
   ├─ FindMysqlConnectorCpp.cmake
src/
├─ app/
├─ common/
├─ core/
├─ CMakeLists.txt
CMakeLists.txt
```

root/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5)

# set the build type
if(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)
    set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
endif(NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Debug)
  message("Debug build.")
elseif(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
  message("Release build.")
endif()

set(application_name "cmake-project-template")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(application_version "1.0.2")
set(PROJECT_VER ${application_version})

cmake_policy(SET CMP0048 NEW)

project (${application_name} LANGUAGES C CXX)

# set search path for CMake modules
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/Modules)
find_package(MysqlConnectorCpp REQUIRED)

add_subdirectory(ThirdParty)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

src/app/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
set(source
    src/main.cpp
    src/appLib.cpp
)

add_library(app ${source})

target_include_directories(app PUBLIC inc)
target_include_directories(app PRIVATE inc/app)

target_include_directories(app ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(app PUBLIC
common
core
${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY} )

add_dependencies(app ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY})

# TODO:
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} app core)
```

src/core/CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
set(source
    src/coreLib.cpp
)

add_library(core ${source})

target_include_directories(core PUBLIC inc)
target_include_directories(core PRIVATE inc/core)

target_include_directories(core ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_INCLUDE_DIR})

include_directories(${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(core PUBLIC
                            common
                            ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY} )

add_dependencies(app ${MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_LIBRARY})
```

Error message:

```bash
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find MysqlConnectorCpp (missing: MYSQLCONNECTORCPP_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  cmake/Modules/FindMysqlConnectorCpp.cmake:59 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:29 (find_package)
```

Comment: "How to build mysql-connecor-cpp using find_package in a CMake project?" -  `find_package` doesn't build anything. It finds pre-built resources.

Comment: @JesperJuhl You're right! Sorry for misunderstanging title, I'll update.